# A question about ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans

Tags: java, jvm

i want to count the number of fullgc, this is my code

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long fullGcCount = 0;
        for(GarbageCollectorMXBean bean: ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
            System.out.println(bean.getName());
            if(bean.getName().equals("ConcurrentMarkSweep")) {
                logger.info("init fullgc count:{}", bean.getCollectionCount());
                while (true) {
                    long temGcCount = bean.getCollectionCount();
                    if(temGcCount == fullGcCount) {
                        continue;
                    }else {
                        System.out.println(String.format("before the FullGC, sum of fullgc:%s, add FullGC count:%s", fullGcCount, temGcCount - fullGcCount));
                        fullGcCount = temGcCount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

i run `jmap -histo:live` 2 times.
this is the first gc log：

```
2023-01-10T19:18:03.496+0800: 80595.099: [Full GC (Heap Inspection Initiated GC) 80595.099: [CMS[YG occupancy: 168131 K (188736 K)]80595.174: [weak refs processing, 0.0015483 secs]80595.176: [class unloading, 0.0253856 secs]80595.201: [scrub symbol table, 0.0237105 secs]80595.225: [scrub string table, 0.0020402 secs]: 112558K->83931K(838912K), 0.2212898 secs] 280689K->252063K(1027648K), [Metaspace: 117424K->117424K(1155072K)], 0.2218481 secs] [Times: user=0.39 sys=0.04, real=0.22 secs]
```

this is the second gc log：

```
2023-01-10T19:18:29.536+0800: 80621.139: [Full GC (Heap Inspection Initiated GC) 80621.139: [CMS: 83931K->85173K(838912K), 0.3054333 secs] 108263K->85173K(1027648K), [Metaspace: 117022K->117022K(1155072K)], 0.3058419 secs] [Times: user=0.29 sys=0.01, real=0.31 secs]
```

It looks like one at a time. But my program thinks the first one is 2 fullgc.

```
......
before the FullGC, sum of fullgc:1, add FullGC count:2
before the FullGC, sum of fullgc:3, add FullGC count:1
......
```

but i do not know why. please help!

i use the google but not find the answer.

Comment: So you’re initializing `fullGcCount` with zero and the first printout of the value shows “one”, despite there is no assignment to this variable before the print statement?

Comment: @Holger My doubt is why the first "add FullGC count" is 1, and the second "add FullGC count" is 2. i think the both fullgc is 1.

Comment: Why does it print `1` when *there is no assignment to `fullGcCount` before the first print statement*. The only place where `fullGcCount` is assigned, is *after* the print statement, hence, it should be impossible to print anything else but the initial zero in the first execution of the print statement. It should be impossible to get this output with this code.

Comment: @Holger There was a fullgc when I started, I just didn't post the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cmsgc of 'jmap -histo:live' is foreground. in this model, the gccount will add 1 when 'Initial Mark', 'CMS remark' and 'Sweep'. According to the log, the first gc trigger 'CMS remark' and 'sweep', the second gc trigger 'sweep'.